# Difficulty to display the js file on the shopify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, shopify, shopify-app

I've been trying to display the information on the js file (that is connected with the vuejs files) to display the app inside Shopify but I couldn't be able to find it.

on the Shopify appears the **< script src="main.js" >** where I connect with the JS file but without success displaying it

[image]

Here are the structures of my files

[image]

Here is the index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/primitive-ui/dist/css/main.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
    <title>clicktays</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to clicktays store</h1>

    <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

Here is the main.js file where I connect with the vuejs file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { App },
}).$mount('#app');
```

Here is the app.vue file where I have some information from the website app

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="clicktayslogo">
      <img src="./logoinvert.png" alt="Clicktays logo">
    </div>
    <h1>Welcome to clicktays store</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h2>Types of picture</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a
          href="https://vuejs.org"
          target="_blank"
        >
          Archtecture
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a
          href="https://forum.vuejs.org"
          target="_blank"
        >
          Street
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a
          href="https://chat.vuejs.org"
          target="_blank"
        >
          Nature
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <footer>
      Hey I'm Tayzer
    </footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App'
}
</script>
```

Comment: You have the <div id="app"></div> tag inside the script tag. Move the script tag to be just before </body> Also the <footer> should appear before </body> as well

Comment: Hey @GavinBruce, thanks for your time, I update it but still not showing.

Comment: Do you think that is work to add more files to help to find the solution? Like the index.js and one more vuejs file?

Comment: You have a duplicate id="app". You can remove the id in your `App.vue` component and keep the id in your `index.html`. Do you want to split your project? is vue only a substack or do you want to build your project completely in vuejs? if so, you can move the footer inside App.vue

Comment: Hello @wittgenstein, thanks for your time and the effort, I put all together on the app.vue flie (also the footer) and took out the id="app" but still dont display it. I updated the information

Comment: Hi, the duplicate id's are fine, sry. Can you remove the main.js from the index.html and write this in the main.js: `new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { app }
}).$mount('#app');`  - what happens than?

Comment: Unfortunetaly stay the same (I updated it the scripts here), if you need any more information to, just let me know to add on the question

Comment: Do you use `npm run serve` or `npm run build`? Have you created your vue.js project via the Vue CLI?

Comment: Hello @wittgenstein, I started from zero my project using the "vue create 'project name'" and finally works for me to display it. thank you so much